# How to force template class to use specified type unless specified otherwise?

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization

I have problem with my template class. I specified default type of my template class like that:

```cpp
template < class T = float >
class apple { 
public:
    T x;
    apple(T x): x(x) {}
}
```

However, when I create the object like that:

```cpp
apple obj(2);
```

The type turns into int unless I do that:

```
apple<float> obj(2);
```

How would I make it stay float?

Comment: It seems you are using c++17. Since c++17 `T` can de deduced from initializer, in your case it is `2` - `int`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using c++17

Comment: it uses the type of the literal value you pass. `apple obj(2.0f)` for float, `apple obj(2.0)` for double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this deduction guide to force all argument deductions to resolve to your default arguments:

```
template <class T>
apple(T) -> apple<>;
```

Comment: Using a deduction guide to disable CTAD. This is some deep magic

Comment: @StoryTeller What is CTAD?

Comment: @StoryTeller all those people complaining about the footgun are just missing the fact that you're *supposed* to hold it backwards.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow **C**lass **t**emplate **a**rgument **d**eduction.

Answer (score 3):

Use the specialization for the default template parameter like

```
apple<> obj( 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to modify the constructor:

```
apple(std::enable_if_t<1, T> x): x(x) {}
```

This way the compiler won't be able to deduce `T` from an argument you pass to `x`, and will use the default type for `T` (that you provided) instead.

Comment: And soon [`std::type_identity_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity).